# Objective-c/MVC - where to put CRUD

Tags: iphone, objective-c, model-view-controller

I am new iPhone development and MVC.
I am working on a app that communicates with a server via http(REST/JSON).
And i am wondering where to put my CRUD methods, (which handles data coming and going to the server) - model or controller. 
What does the experienced iPhone dev´s do?

Answer (score 0):

Usually persistence operations always take place in the Model in MVC. Its best to limit the control to business logic only.

Answer (score 0):

The way the framework comes to you, you sort of have to build your own Model layer, either out of Core Data or a data management singleton, or something like that. It's not like some MVC frameworks, where there's a directory of files that are the models.

That said, your web client business is going to take some controller actions to accomplish--maybe they fire when your view loads, or when a button is tapped, or what have you. So I usually put the actions-of-CRUDing functionality in the Controller of whatever view is presented at the time, and populate my Model layer depending on what I get back.

Check out the ASIHTTPRequest and JSON Framework libraries, as they're absolutely central to my building these sorts of things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure REST api, I suggest to use [Restkit](https://github.com/twotoasters/RestKit) or [ObjectiveResource](http://iphoneonrails.com/).